# What is different about Windows 10 security in relation to MSI files?

Tags: windows-installer, windows-10, admin-rights

I have an MSI file built with Wix.  During the install, a powershell process requiring admin rights is launched.  This worked fine under Windows 7, but fails under Windows 10.  I get a UAC prompt upon install in 10, but it doesn't seem to run the install with elevated privileges.

Has something changed from 7 to 10 related to MSI security that would cause this?

**Update**: I agree PowerShell isn't ideal but it is what it is at this point.  The script that is run is executed 'immediate' as opposed to 'deferred', so it won't run with elevated privileges.  This explains the failure on Windows 10, but how did it succeeded on Windows 7?

Comment: First of all: Powershell and other managed code requiring the .NET framework is generally not recommended for MSI deployment. You should rather use minimum dependency custom actions such as C++ dlls, Installscript. Even VBScript or Javascript would be better imho, since MSI hosts its own scripting runtime. Also, if you haven't done so already, please make a verbose log of your installation like this (replace paths obviously): ``msiexec.exe /package "C:\Install.msi" /L*V "C:\msilog.log"``. I would do this for both Windows 7 and Windows 10. That command line runs the MSI interactively.

Comment: See [Rob Mensching's blog](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) for a good manual way to read an MSI log file (essentially you search for "value 3" in the log file). This article from Robert Macdonald from the Windows Installer Team may be useful: [How to Interpret Windows Installer Logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx). Finally: is your custom action properly configured as a **deferred mode custom action**? (immediate mode custom actions can not be elevated)

Comment: As Stein says, post the custom action specification and indicate how it's called.

Comment: .NET managed custom actions using DTF are perfectly fine for installers.  There are some points to be aware of but there is no general reccomendation against them.  WiX does ship DTF for many years now after all.   They just don't use it in their own extensions because they don't want everyone to have to take a dependency on the framework.   Considering that every version of Windows since Vista has had .NET 2.0+ I consider that an outdated approach but so be it.

Comment: I don't advise using PowerShell though because it runs out of process and can't access the windows installer session api.

Comment: Sorry, too many comments. Just want to add that I am 100% with Chris on Powershell. Respectfully, we both think it should not be used since it is so volatile and, frankly, clunky. The decision obviously depends on the scope of your distribution. For small scale deployment it might suffice, for worldwide distribution, please don't roll with it. Not sure on the elevation issue, but Windows 10 probably does UAC elevation correctly. Maybe you launched from a command prompt with real admin rights on Windows 7? Then the immediate custom actions will probably succeed.

Comment: That's what puzzles me - users launch the installer by double clicking on the .msi file.  There's no chance they're running it as admin.

Comment: I have a quiet morning if you want to hit me up and look at it together.

Comment: @Dan: Did you make any progress here Dan?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - In a way I did.  I can't find documentation to support it, but the same .msi behaves differently under Windows 10.  Specifically, there are custom actions that are executed outside of the install transaction, and hence don't run with elevated privileges.  On Windows 10, those fail because they're custom actions that peek at the registry.  On Windows 7, everything works.  My work-around was to create a bootstrapper to run the .msi.